# Enum Property Callback(s) on scroll ? on click ? on release?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

So there is my question today :

I'm working with an enum props for my addon.

This enum contain X Meshs. I want to be able to update the mesh on scrolling then update the enum (for example removing the selected mesh ) on release or on click ?

But for now i found that the only way to update enum is the "update". Is there others callbacks or other way to do this ?

Comment: I see four possible callbacks, on draw (`item` parameter) but I wouldn't put actual logic in this callback, on get, set or update. see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty AFAIK there is no way with the API to easily see which item is under the cursor without a tremendous amount of work. Maybe you can rethink the way your addon works around this property ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gorgious ! I will find a workaround , i was curious to see if i'm missed something. Maybe that's something we could ask for ?